# Android - Is the xlarge layout size ever needed for phones?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app project for school, I need to use `Fragments` to make the app's UI scalable on as many phone screen sizes as possible. I'm currently doing it for small, normal, and large screen sizes.

However, I'm a little iffy on whether I should do it for xlarge screen sizes. Isn't that size category only for tablets? Are there any phones or phablets that are in the xlarge screen size category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per what [Google Android Developers guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) thinks: `xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp`

A quick search on Google finds a few phones larger than this, E.G.: [ASUS FonePad](http://smartphones.specout.com/l/2542/Asus-FonePad-8) at 1,280 x 800 pixels. That's a relatively low density screen (189 PPI), so quite a few phones probably top that one.

EDIT: The highest I've found so far is the [Samsung Galaxy Note 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Note_5) at 2560×1440 more than double the minimum for xlarge layout. Also worth noting this is a relatively popular smartphone so is a more likely use case.

Comment: Thanks, I think google should be for regulating about idiotic companies not making screen sizes that are consistent with certain categories. It make Android development more of a pain because certain users will complain about apps not displaying nicely on their devices...